# GL_INVALID_OPERATION on random opengl es 2.0 functions

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am executing the following C++ code in the middle of my game (everything is running fine except this), and I'm not running it while rendering:

```
MetaBalls::MetaBalls() : largeTexture(NULL), metaballsShader(NULL), smallTexture(NULL), smallFBO(0), largeFBO(0) {

// 1. Compile shader that will render small texture onto larger texture using blur threshold
CRender::Instance()->CreateShader("Shaders/metaballs.fs", "Shaders/metaballs.vs", &metaballsShader);
metaballsShader->_locations["projview"] = glGetUniformLocation(metaballsShader->_program, "projview");

// 4. Load the sprite that will be rendered as particles on the small texture
// TODO: batch render this
m_metaballSprite.InitSprite("Embellishments/particle.png", OFFSCREEN);

// 2. Create new texture and 2 frame buffers
// First frame buffer to render small texture, second frame buffer to scale small texture up into big one
glGenTextures(1, &smallTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, smallTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8_OES, SMALL_TEX_W, SMALL_TEX_H, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

// 3. Create second larger texture to contain final water textured (rendered in game as sprite)
glGenTextures(1, &largeTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, largeTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8_OES, LARGE_TEX_W, LARGE_TEX_H, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

// 5. Attach small texture to frame buffer
glGenFramebuffers(1, &smallFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, smallFBO);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, smallTexture);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, smallTexture, 0);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    s3eDebugErrorShow(S3E_MESSAGE_CONTINUE_STOP, "Metaballs small framebuffer incomplete");
}

// 6. Attach large texture to other frame buffer
glGenFramebuffers(1, &largeFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, largeFBO);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, largeTexture);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, largeTexture, 0);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    s3eDebugErrorShow(S3E_MESSAGE_CONTINUE_STOP, "Metaballs small framebuffer incomplete");
}

// 7. Build geometry for small frame buffer
float w = PTM_DOWNSCALE(SMALL_TEX_W);
float h = PTM_DOWNSCALE(SMALL_TEX_H);
CRender::Instance()->BuildQuad(
    tVertex( b2Vec3(0,0,0), b2Vec2(0,1) ),
    tVertex( b2Vec3(w,0,0), b2Vec2(1,1) ),
    tVertex( b2Vec3(w,h,0), b2Vec2(1,0) ),
    tVertex( b2Vec3(0,h,0), b2Vec2(0,0) ),
    smallBuffer);

// 8. Build geometry for large frame buffer
w = PTM_DOWNSCALE(SMALL_TEX_W);
h = PTM_DOWNSCALE(SMALL_TEX_H);
CRender::Instance()->BuildQuad(
    tVertex( b2Vec3(0,0,0), b2Vec2(0,1) ),
    tVertex( b2Vec3(w,0,0), b2Vec2(1,1) ),
    tVertex( b2Vec3(w,h,0), b2Vec2(1,0) ),
    tVertex( b2Vec3(0,h,0), b2Vec2(0,0) ),
    largeBuffer);

// return to default state
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting this error reported from OpenGL ES 2.0:

```
GL Error GL_INVALID_OPERATION on entry to function glGenFramebuffers(1, 0xd8450e8)
```

If I switch the order of the above opengl calls near the start of the function I can get GL_INVALID_OPERATION occuring on either of the glGenTextures lines, glBindFramebuffer, or even glCreateProgram() which is executed inside the first CreateShader function. Although with the current call order, the shader is loading and compiling fine.

The error I am getting breaks the documented results of these calls on opengl.org, for example, glGenFramebuffers should only return GL_INVALID_OPERATION if you pass a non-zero value that glGenFrameBuffers did not return. However, I have checked the integers returned from glGenFrameBuffers... they are 2 and 3. Nothing wrong with those since I already have a third frame buffer elseware. I also tried generating both textures and frame buffers at once but they produce the same GLuint's and the same errors occur.

Any idea how this error could possibly be caused?? I've had similar code running in this class no problem in the past.

Comment: You're not invoking this in a `glBegin / glEnd` block I assume?

Comment: Hi, nope definitely not. I suspect it's an issue with glGenTextures/glTexImage2D since even though I copied the example directly from Apple, I've never been able to get them to work, so in my game if I've wanted a blank texture I just load a pre-defined size PNG file instead of generating it in memory. Don't know why that doesn't work (I don't get any errors about it, just really weird things like this). Actually is it possible these errors are leaking through from other functions and only crashing when they really matter?

Comment: Indeed it worked by initially filling the texture with data in glTexImage2D like this: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)textureImage) but why? Using GL_RGBA as the third parameter didn't make a difference. If I simply make the last parameter NULL I get all these weird errors....